# Property 'mylabel' not found on object of type 'uitableviewcell'

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, iboutlet

I am trying to connect a label from `storyboard` and get this `error`.

> Property 'mylabel' not found on object of type 'uitableviewcell'

in the `FilterDemoTableViewController.m`

```
cell.mylabel.text = food.name;
```

[screenshot of error in FilterDemoTableViewController.m](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzumG.png)

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *mylabel;


@end
```

Comment: Have you set the class of the cell in Interface Builder to the custom class?

Comment: You can't assign properties like that in a .h; do you mean .m?  Can you show more code. For example, how do you declare `cell`?  My guess is as a `UITableViewCell *` rather than `TableViewCell *`

Comment: Yes I have vadian. Yeah I mean TableViewCell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before use your `cell` you have to **cast** to your type.

```
TableViewCell *cell = (TableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
cell.mylabel.text = food.name;
```

Now you can access normally.

Comment: Thank you that did the trick, before I had UITableViewCell instead of TableViewCell in the cellForRowAtIndexPath